# How to catch exceptions when connecting to MongoDB in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, exception

How can I catch exceptions caused by following code?

```
try {
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(
                                  cu.getName(), 
                                  "admin",
                                  cu.getPassword().toCharArray());

    ServerAddress address = new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017);

    mongoClient = new MongoClient(address, Arrays.asList(credential));

} catch (MongoSecurityException e) {
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

I do get exceptions in stacktrace, but I'm not able to catch them though.

> Mai 29, 2017 1:04:37 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
>   INFORMATION: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
>   Mai 29, 2017 1:04:37 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
>   INFORMATION: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
>   com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='root', source='admin', password=, mechanismProperties={}}
>       at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapInMongoSecurityException(SaslAuthenticator.java:157)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$200(SaslAuthenticator.java:37)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:66)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:44)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:162)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:44)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:32)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:109)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:46)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:116)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed" }
>       at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.createCommandFailureException(CommandHelper.java:170)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:123)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslContinue(SaslAuthenticator.java:121)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$100(SaslAuthenticator.java:37)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:63)
>       ... 9 more
>   `

Comment: If you look at the rest your backtrace, you'll probably see that the code that throws is not inside your try block.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an authentication problem:

> com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='root', source='admin', password=, mechanismProperties={}} at ...`

Looking at your code I see it's called `MongoCredential.createCredential()` which accepts 3 parameters (user, database and password).

Assuming that your credentials are correct I strongly suspect that `admin` is NOT your database name.

Comment: Yes, exaclty. That's the exception I want to catch.